# How can a parent-process find out if the child-process was terminated?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, fork, parent-child

I want to write a program in which the parent creates exactly 1 child process. The child process should print its pid to the standard output and then finish. The parent process should waits until it is sure that the child has terminated. The parent terminates after it has waited for the child process.

Thats what I got so far:

```
#include <unistd.h>     
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{ 
    int child;
    child = fork();
    if (child == 0)
        {
            printf("Child process has PID: %d. \n", getpid());
            exit(0);    
        }

        // how can the parent process find out it the child process was terminated successful? 

        printf("Child process terminated successfully\n");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

How can the parent-process find out if the child process was terminated? I can't use wait() or waitpid() in this programm.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: look at _SIGCHLD_ signal

Comment: Just for clarity, *why* can't you use `wait` or `waitpid`? That's the normal solution to this problem.

Comment: @DanielPryden visibly the OP does not want to be blocked, using SIGCHILD is the solution

Comment: Of course the parent wants to be blocked, @bruno.  There is no other reasonable interpretation of "The parent process should ***waits*** [sic] until it is sure that the child has terminated" (emphasis added).

Comment: @JohnBollinger I say that because of the end of the question after the code. Do not say me you never implemented a manager starting processes and where you do not want to be blocked even managing child termination. why do I often feel like you're just going to contradict me or kill me? I am really tired of that !

Comment: As an aside, I note that although one can be reasonably confident in interpreting a `SIGCHLD` to indicate that the child has terminated in this case, the only way I know to be absolutely *sure* is to use one of the `wait()` family of functions.  A process also dispatches a `SIGCHLD` to its parent when it is stopped, and, subject to access controls, any random process can send a `SIGCHLD` to any other at any time, so these are not sure indications of termination.

Answer (score 3):

When a child process terminates a SIGCHLD signal will be sent to the parent, by default the parent will ignore the SIGCHLD, however you can register a signal handler that will catch it.

You need to be careful what you do in the signal handler - quite a few standard function aren't safe to use.

The SIGCHLD approach turns up in code when the parent has it's own work to do and can't just wait for the child.  If the parent just spawns children and then waits for them to finish the wait() and waitpid() are the best solution.

Finally if you don't call wait() or waitpid() you risk creating a zombie process, the child process expects it's parent to receive it's exit status through a call to one of these functions.

Comment: Actually I think there is a default `SIGCHLD` handler, which is used by the implementation of `wait`, at least on some OSs?

Answer (score 1):

As I said in remark use the signal *SIGCHLD*, for instance :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void handler(int sig)
{
  pid_t chpid = wait(NULL);

  /* WARNING : to show the call of the handler, do not do that
     in a 'real' code, we are in a handler of a signal */
  printf("Child pid %d ended (signal %s)\n", chpid, sig); 

  /* does 'something' to allow the parent to know chpid 
     terminated in a way compatible with parent requirement */
}

int main(void)
{
  signal(SIGCHLD, handler);

  if (!fork())
  {
    printf("Child pid is %d\n", getpid());
    sleep(1);
    return 0;
  }
  printf("Parent pid is %d\n", getpid());
  getchar();

  return 0;
}
```

Note when the signal arrive you have to call *wait(NULL)* but because by definition the child terminated the function returns immediately

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wextra s.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Parent pid is 21743
Child pid is 21744
Child pid 21744 ended (signal 17)
<enter>
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Of course the signal 17 is *SIGCHLD* because it is the only one the program catches

Comment: printf() is one of those standard functions you shouldn't use in a signal handler.  A better approach is to set a flag in the signal handler and then loop in the main code until the flag is set.  The signal man page should list the functions that are allowed.

Comment: @Jackson this is for the demo to help the OP to see what appends ;-) I edited my answer to warn about

Comment: Ok, but I'd make that clear in the post if you can.  This approach can break if another signal is received as the first one is being processed.

Comment: It really doesn't help anybody to hand out complete solutions to academic exercises.

Comment: @JohnBollinger you never learn like that ? sad. Fortunately is/was different for me ^^ (but may be I understood wrongly your remark ?)

Comment: @bruno It can be used for learning for some people, but it can also lead to cargo cult programming.

Comment: @bruno, the point of an instructor posing an exercise is for the student to solve it *themselves*.  The process of working out the solution provides most of the educational value.  If it were otherwise then there would be no exercises, only examples to study.

Comment: @JohnBollinger more seriously, the code I give just do a (not recommended) _printf_ to show the execution, but in fact the parent does not 'really' know the child terminated, there is no side effect for the rest of the execution, it is not at all a full solution

Comment: @ChristianGibbons what _cargo cult programming_ expression means ?

Comment: @bruno *Cargo Cult* refers to a method of programming that involves copy-pasting code without fully understanding how it works. They know that a particular segment of code accomplishes a particular task, but not necessarily how or why. It comes from--I want to say--the Vietnam War where countries would set up airfields to supply their war efforts. The indigenous people recognized that these airfields would bring cargo, so they tried to build their own replica airfields and airplanes out of straw in hopes that it would bring cargo-carrying airplanes. These became known as *cargo cults*.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons ah ok, thank you for that explanation

Comment: Cargo Cults go back to the Pacific in WW2, my favourite is the one that developed on Vanuatu that worships Prince Philip.